# Binding data from a library to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm working on a project that uses [ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf). I want to bind the `TitleBar.Background` to GetBG.
Here's my code:

```cs
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ModernWpf;

namespace TestApp.Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Color GetBG()
            {
                var bc = new BrushConverter();
                if (ModernWpf.ThemeManager.GetRequestedTheme(window).ToString() == "Black" || ModernWpf.ThemeManager.GetRequestedTheme(window).ToString() == "Dark")
                {
                    return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#1E1E1E");
                }
                else { return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#E6E6E6"); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="OpenRelease.Desktop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ui:ThemeManager.RequestedTheme="Light"

        <!---Here's where i want to use the binding.--->
        ui:TitleBar.Background="{GetBG}"

        ui:TitleBar.IsIconVisible="False"
        ui:ThemeManager.IsThemeAware="True"
        xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
        ui:WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle="True"
        Title="TestApp" Height="850" Width="1260">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Edit, I renamed GetBG and made it public in the MainWindow.cs file:

```cs
public Color ThemeAwareBackground()
        {
            var bc = new BrushConverter();
            if (ModernWpf.ThemeManager.GetRequestedTheme(window).ToString() == "Black" || ModernWpf.ThemeManager.GetRequestedTheme(window).ToString() == "Dark")
            {
                return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#1E1E1E");
            }
            else { return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#E6E6E6"); }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make it property not local function then bind it like `{Binding ThemeAwareBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Comment: It doesn't work. It displays an error, saying that GetBG doesn't exist. XLS0432 The property 'GetBG' was not found in type 'MainWindow'.

Comment: ***Make it property not local function*** <= did you read this?  after i've change comment you should call property `ThemeAwareBackground`  (because calling property `GetBG` is not nice) it can have only getter but should be public

Comment: Still no succes. It still displays an error that ThemeAwareBackground doesn't exist.

Comment: *ThemeAwareBackground doesn't exist* Yeah, I bet ... did you added ? you have `Color GetBG()`  make it property of `MainWindow` called `ThemeAwareBackground` (as obviosuly you cannot bind to method - especially local)

Comment: I did that. And tried again but still no success.

Comment: is it public ..?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for helping btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binding to work it needs to be a dependency property and I believe it should set a brush and not a color.  Here is a possible implementation of a dependency property that may work; in the constructor the correct value can be determined using code similar to what you have in your original GetBG() and set the value of the dependency property.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ThemeAwareBackgroundBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ThemeAwareBackgroundBrush),
        typeof(SolidColorBrush),
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush)));

public SolidColorBrush ThemeAwareBackgroundBrush
{
    get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(ThemeAwareBackgroundBrushProperty);
    set => SetValue(ThemeAwareBackgroundBrushProperty, value);
}
```